# Play 2.5 Scala what's the standard way to define Forms?

Tags: scala, playframework

Trying to migrate this Play 2.5 Java [play-authenticate-usage](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/tree/master/samples/java/play-authenticate-usage) project to Scala 
[play-authenticate-usage-scala](https://github.com/bravegag/play-authenticate-usage-scala) I have bumped into the issue of the [Forms declaration and handling](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaForms). In the Java version they are defined (at least in that project) as a static class inside the controller class e.g.

```
public class Account extends Controller {
  public static class PasswordChange {
    @MinLength(5)
    @Required
    public String password;

    @MinLength(5)
    @Required
    public String repeatPassword;

    public String validate() {
      if (password == null || !password.equals(repeatPassword)) {
        return Messages.get("playauthenticate.change_password.error.passwords_not_same");
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }
    // ... 
  }

  // ...
  private final Form<Account.PasswordChange> PASSWORD_CHANGE_FORM;
}
```

The `PasswordChange` class is then statically referenced from views and other classes. The only way I found to replicate that in Scala was to define controller Account companion object e.g.

```
/**
  * Account companion object
  */
object Account {
  case class PasswordChange(password: String, repeatPassword: String)
  val PasswordChangeForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "password" -> text(minLength = 5),
      "repeatPassword" -> text(minLength = 5)
    )(PasswordChange.apply)(PasswordChange.unapply)
  )
}
```

Is this the standard practice or? is there a better way to do it? to me defining controller companion objects feels like a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the documentation with the examples at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaForms ?

Comment: Yep, there is no reference to where the Form case and mapping classes should live in connection with the enclosing controller.

Comment: i like to define the form near the model (case class) object to which it refers (in CRUD cases)